# WordPress customizer and webpack - exposing wp global

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, webpack

I'm using webpack to bundle my files. And I want to add a script that will enable me to change settings in the customizer on the fly.

I created a class which will hold all my customizer functionality

```
<?php
/**
 * The Customizer specific functionality.
 *
 * @since   1.0.0
 * @package mytheme
 */

namespace MyTheme\Customizer;

use MyTheme\Helpers as Helpers;

/**
 * Class Customizer
 */
class Customizer {

  /**
   * Global theme name
   *
   * @var string
   *
   * @since 1.0.0
   */
  protected $theme_name;

  /**
   * Global theme version
   *
   * @var string
   *
   * @since 1.0.0
   */
  protected $theme_version;

  /**
   * Initialize class
   *
   * @param array                  $theme_info Load global theme info.
   * @param Helpers\General_Helper $helpers Instance of the General Helpers object.
   *
   * @since 1.0.0
   */
  public function __construct( $theme_info = null, Helpers\General_Helper $helpers ) {
    $this->theme_name    = $theme_info['theme_name'];
    $this->theme_version = $theme_info['theme_version'];

    $this->helpers = $helpers;

  }

  /**
   * Register customizer settings
   *
   * @see add_action('customize_register',$func)
   * @param  \WP_Customize_Manager $wp_customize WP Customize object.
   * @since 1.0.0
   */
  public function register_customizer_settings( \WP_Customize_Manager $wp_customize ) {
    // Abort if selective refresh is not available.
    if ( ! isset( $wp_customize->selective_refresh ) ) {
      return;
    }

    /**
     * Footer section
     */
    $wp_customize->add_section( 'footer_section', array(
        'title'    => esc_html__( 'Footer', 'mytheme' ),
        'priority' => 100,
    ) );

    /**
     * Copyright notice
     */
    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'footer_copyright', array(
        'default'           => '',
        'type'              => 'theme_mod',
        'transport'         => 'postMessage',
        'sanitize_callback' => 'wp_kses_post',
    ) );

    $wp_customize->add_control( 'footer_copyright', array(
        'label'       => esc_html__( 'Footer Copyright Text', 'mytheme' ),
        'section'     => 'footer_section',
        'type'        => 'text',
    ) );
  }

  /**
   * Enqueue live preview script
   *
   * @since 1.0.0
   */
  public function live_preview_enqueue() {
    $customizer_script = '/skin/public/scripts/customizer.js';

    wp_register_script( $this->theme_name . '-customizer', get_template_directory_uri() . $customizer_script, array(), $this->helpers->get_assets_version( $customizer_script ) );
    wp_enqueue_script( $this->theme_name . '-customizer', array( 'jquery', 'customize-preview' ), false );
  }
}
```

In another class where I load my actions I have

```
private function define_customizer_hooks() {
  $customizer = new Customizer\Customizer( $this->get_theme_info(), new Helpers\General_Helper() );

  $this->loader->add_action( 'customize_register', $customizer, 'register_customizer_settings', 11 );
  $this->loader->add_action( 'customize_preview_init', $customizer, 'live_preview_enqueue' );
}
```

Now, I can see my settings just fine. The `Footer section` is showing. But I get an error in my console

> jQuery.Deferred exception: wp.customize is not a function TypeError: wp.customize is not a function

The **customizer.js** looks like this

```
/* global wp */
$(function() {
  wp.customize('footer_copyright', (value) => {
    value.bind((newval) => {
      if ($('.footer__copyright').length) {
        if (newval !== '') {
          if ($('.footer__copyright').hasClass('hide')) {
            $('.footer__copyright').removeClass('hide').text(newval);
          } else {
            $('.footer__copyright').text(newval);
          }
        } else {
          $('.footer__copyright').addClass('hide');
        }
      } else {
        $('.footer__container').append(`<div class="footer__copyright">${newval}</div>`);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

And my **webpack.config.js** looks like this:

```
/* global process __dirname */

const DEV = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';

const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const BrowserSyncPlugin = require('browser-sync-webpack-plugin');
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');

const appPath = `${path.resolve(__dirname)}`;

// Dev Server
const proxyUrl = 'mytheme.test';

// Theme
const themeName = 'mytheme';
const themePath = `/wp-content/themes/${themeName}/skin`;
const themeFullPath = `${appPath}${themePath}`;
const themePublicPath = `${themePath}/public/`;
const themeEntry = `${themeFullPath}/assets/application.js`;
const themeAdminEntry = `${themeFullPath}/assets/application-admin.js`;
const themeGutenbergEntry = `${themeFullPath}/assets/application-gutenberg.js`;
const themeCustomizerEntry = `${themeFullPath}/assets/customizer.js`;
const themeOutput = `${themeFullPath}/public`;

// Outputs
const outputJs = 'scripts/[name].js';
const outputCss = 'styles/[name].css';
const outputFile = '[name].[ext]';
const outputImages = `images/${outputFile}`;
const outputFonts = `fonts/${outputFile}`;

const allModules = {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
      use: 'babel-loader',
      exclude: /node_modules/,
    },
    {
      test: /\.json$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      use: 'file-loader',
    },
    {
      test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$/,
      exclude: [/fonts/, /node_modules/],
      use: `file-loader?name=${outputImages}`,
    },
    {
      test: /\.(eot|otf|ttf|woff|woff2|svg)$/,
      exclude: [/images/, /node_modules/],
      use: `file-loader?name=${outputFonts}`,
    },
    {
      test: /\.scss$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      use: [
        MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
        'css-loader', 'postcss-loader', 'sass-loader',
      ],
    },
  ],
};

const allPlugins = [
  new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
    filename: outputCss,
  }),

  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery',
  }),

  // Use BrowserSync For assets
  new BrowserSyncPlugin({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 3000,
    proxy: proxyUrl,
    files: [
      {
        match: ['wp-content/themes/**/*.php', 'wp-content/plugins/**/*.php'],
      },
    ],
  }),

  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'process.env': {
      NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'),
    },
  }),

  new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, /moment$/),
];

const allOptimizations = {
  runtimeChunk: false,
  splitChunks: {
    cacheGroups: {
      commons: {
        test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
        name: 'vendors',
        chunks: 'all',
      },
    },
  },
};

// Use only for production build
if (!DEV) {
  allOptimizations.minimizer = [
    new UglifyJsPlugin({
      cache: true,
      parallel: true,
      sourceMap: true,
      uglifyOptions: {
        output: {
          comments: false,
        },
        compress: {
          warnings: false,
          drop_console: true, // eslint-disable-line camelcase
        },
      },
    }),
  ];
  allPlugins.push(new CleanWebpackPlugin([themeOutput]));
}

module.exports = [

  // Theme Skin
  {
    context: path.join(__dirname),
    entry: {
      application: [themeEntry],
      applicationAdmin: [themeAdminEntry],
      themeGutenberg: [themeGutenbergEntry],
      customizer: [themeCustomizerEntry],
    },
    output: {
      path: themeOutput,
      publicPath: themePublicPath,
      filename: outputJs,
      library: ['wp', '[name]'],
      libraryTarget: 'var',
    },

    externals: {
      wp: 'wp',
    },

    optimization: allOptimizations,

    mode: 'production',

    module: allModules,

    plugins: allPlugins,

    devtool: DEV ? '#inline-source-map' : '',
  },
];
```

and **package.json** is

```
{
  "name": "mytheme",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "author": "dingo_d",
  "private": true,
  "main": "",
  "scripts": {
    "__sassUnusedTheme": "sass-unused \"wp-content/themes/init_theme_name/**/*.scss\"",
    "__eslintTheme": "eslint wp-content/themes/init_theme_name/skin/assets/",
    "__stylelintTheme": "stylelint \"wp-content/themes/init_theme_name/**/*.scss\" --syntax scss",
    "precommitCss": "npm run __stylelintTheme",
    "precommitCssUnused": "npm run __sassUnusedTheme",
    "precommitJs": "npm run __eslintTheme",
    "precommit": "npm run precommitJs && npm run precommitCss && npm run precommitCssUnused",
    "start": "webpack --progress --watch --display-error-details --display-reasons",
    "build": "NODE_ENV=production webpack --progress"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@infinumjs/eslint-config": "^1.1.0",
    "@infinumjs/stylelint-config": "^1.0.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.2.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "browser-sync": "^2.24.1",
    "browser-sync-webpack-plugin": "^2.2.2",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.19",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
    "eslint": "^4.19.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.11.0",
    "expose-loader": "^0.7.5",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.2",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.11",
    "imports-loader": "^0.8.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.4.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.0",
    "postcss-cssnext": "^3.1.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^2.1.4",
    "precss": "^3.1.2",
    "sass-loader": "^7.0.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.21.0",
    "stylelint": "^9.2.0",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.2.5",
    "webpack": "^4.6.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.1.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^8.4.1",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "bugsnag-js": "^4.6.0",
    "css-mqpacker": "^6.0.2",
    "cssnano": "^3.10.0",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "jquery-match-height": "^0.7.2",
    "layzr.js": "^2.2.2",
    "media-blender": "^2.1.0",
    "normalize.css": "^8.0.0",
    "npm": "^6.0.0",
    "postcss-font-magician": "^2.1.1",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "whatwg-fetch": "^2.0.4"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "android >= 4.2",
    "not ie < 11",
    "last 2 versions",
    "Safari >= 8"
  ]
}
```

The thing that bothers me is that I basically used (and modified) my code that works in the theme that is built without all the fancy build tools (https://themes.svn.wordpress.org/expire/1.0.9/inc/customizer/js/customizer.js)

I tried with

```
/* global wp */
(function(api) {
  api('footer_copyright', (value) => {
    value.bind((newval) => {
      if ($('.footer__copyright').length) {
        if (newval !== '') {
          if ($('.footer__copyright').hasClass('hide')) {
            $('.footer__copyright').removeClass('hide').text(newval);
          } else {
            $('.footer__copyright').text(newval);
          }
        } else {
          $('.footer__copyright').addClass('hide');
        }
      } else {
        $('.footer__container').append(`<div class="footer__copyright">${newval}</div>`);
      }
    });
  });
})(wp.customize);
```

But again, I got

> Uncaught ReferenceError: wp is not defined

And in the inspector, probably after everything is loaded the `wp.customize` is available (`ƒ (){return f.instance.apply(f,arguments)}`).

I followed advice given by the [Gutenberg](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/9870e81b6298ba79272002acf92e9ee326e1458c/webpack.config.js#L133-L134) team, who are using webpack, but I'm not sure I'm doing it right.

Comment: Isn't `wp` available in the global scope already? Have you tried using `window.wp`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is the best solution but I decided to add a dependency in my `wp_enqueue_script` call. For example I initially had:

```
wp_enqueue_script('scripts/admin/remove_category.js', asset_path('scripts/admin/remove_category.js'));
```

But then I had a search through the WordPress JS files to see which ones used `wp`, I figured I could pick an arbitrary one of these to use as a dependency and subsequently ensure `wp` is available inside my script, like this:

```
wp_enqueue_script('scripts/admin/remove_category.js', asset_path('scripts/admin/remove_category.js'), ['wp-util']);
```

Comment: I think this is the way to go. I haven't tested it, but some combination of setting the dependency and exposing the necessary scripts in webpack should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

The `wp` object is already available in the global scope. From WordPress' [JavaScript Reference/wp](https://codex.wordpress.org/Javascript_Reference/wp):

> The window.wp object is used to namespace multiple useful Javascript
>   class objects for WordPress's admin.

Changing `wp.customize` to `window.wp.customize` should do the trick.

Comment: I tried this, but it's not working. I'm not sure why, exactly because it should be a globally available object.

Answer (score 0):

Customizer has some useful actions for enqueue scripts:

- If you're hooking in JS code to affect the controls in the customizer, then you would want to use `customize_controls_enqueue_scripts`.
- If you're hooking in JS code to be in the preview frame and possibly
  to receive events from the controls via postMessage, and thus able to
  dynamically change the contents of the preview frame rapidly, you
  would use `customize_preview_init`.

So I think in your case you should use `customize_controls_enqueue_scripts` to enqueue script with `wp_enqueue_script` function.

@see https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/138646/90804